# site to site openvpn with Merlin and DD-WRT

Tags: openvpn, site-to-site-vpn

I am trying to setup an OpenVPN site to site between site A(Server-Merlin) and site B(Client DD-WRT). The tunnel comes up and both peers are able to ping each other but when anyone on the client subnet(10.1.30.0/24) tries to ping any host on the server side(10.1.10.0/24)  packets are being dropped by the server since the server doesn't know how to get to client's subnet even after adding the route.
Here are the configs:

**Server**

> ## Automatically generated configuration
>
> daemon
>
> server 172.16.254.0 255.255.255.248
>
> proto udp
>
> port 1198
>
> dev tun21
>
> cipher AES-256-CBC
>
> comp-lzo adaptive
>
> keepalive 15 60
>
> verb 3
>
> push "route 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0"
>
> client-config-dir ccd
>
> client-to-client
>
> duplicate-cn
>
> ca ca.crt
>
> dh dh.pem
>
> cert server.crt
>
> key server.key
>
> status-version 2
>
> status status
>
> ## Custom Configuration
>
> ifconfig 172.16.254.1 255.255.255.248M
>
> management 127.0.0.1 5001M
>
> auth none

**Firewall - Server**

> iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp --dport 1198 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun21 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -I FORWARD -i tun21 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

**Routing table Server:**

> 172.16.254.2 dev tun21  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.254.1
>
> x.x.x.x dev eth0  scope link
>
> 172.16.254.0/29 via 172.16.254.2 dev tun21
>
> x.x.x.x/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src x.x.x.x
>
> 10.1.10.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.10.254
>
> 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
>
> default via x.x.x.x dev eth0

**Client Config:**

> ca /tmp/openvpncl/ca.crt
>
> cert /tmp/openvpncl/client.crt
>
> key /tmp/openvpncl/client.key
>
> management 127.0.0.1 5001
>
> management-log-cache 50
>
> verb 4
>
> mute 3
>
> log-append /var/log/openvpncl
>
> writepid /var/run/openvpncl.pid
>
> client
>
> resolv-retry infinite
>
> nobind
>
> persist-key
>
> persist-tun
>
> script-security 2
>
> mtu-disc yes
>
> dev tun1
>
> proto udp
>
> cipher aes-256-cbc
>
> auth none
>
> remote x.x.x.x 1198
>
> comp-lzo adaptive
>
> tun-mtu 1500
>
> fast-io

**Client Firewall**

> iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp --dport 1198 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -I FORWARD -i tun1 -o br0 -j ACCEPT

**Client routing table:**

> Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
>
> 0.0.0.0         192.168.2.253   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
>
> 10.1.10.0       172.16.254.5    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1
>
> 10.1.30.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
>
> 127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
>
> 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
>
> 172.16.254.0    172.16.254.5    255.255.255.248 UG    0      0        0 tun1
>
> 172.16.254.5    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
>
> 192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
>
> 239.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 br0

What is weird is that on the client side the tun device has an IP of 172.16.254.6 while the gateway is 172.16.254.5 and on the server side the IP is 172.16.254.1 and the tun IP is 172.16.254.2. On the server side I can't ping 172.16.254.2 but I can ping the tun IP of  the client(172.16.254.6) and vice versa on the client side I can't ping 172.16.254.5 which is the gateway but I can ping 172.16.254.1.

**Server interfaces**

> ip addr
>
> 1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue
>
> link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>
> inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
>
> 2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> inet x.x.x.x/28 brd x.x.x.x scope global eth0
>
> 3: eth1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 4: eth2:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 5: vlan1@eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 6: vlan2@eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> 7: br0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue
>
> link/ether d8:50:e6:cb:f5:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>
> inet 10.1.10.254/24 brd 10.1.10.255 scope global br0
>
> 8: tun21:  mtu 1500 qdisc
>
> pfifo_fast qlen 100
>
> link/[65534]
>
> inet 172.16.254.1 peer 172.16.254.2/32 scope global tun21

Client interfaces:

> ath0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F6
>
> ```
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:2528056 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:3317121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
>
>      RX bytes:177453174 (169.2 MiB)  TX bytes:539912763 (514.9 MiB)
> ```
>
> ath1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F7
>
> ```
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:12502 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
>
>      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1688459 (1.6 MiB)
> ```
>
> br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F6
>
> ```
>      inet addr:10.1.30.251  Bcast:10.1.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:3715741 errors:0 dropped:3772 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:5006361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>
>      RX bytes:415672171 (396.4 MiB)  TX bytes:6820174338 (6.3 GiB)
> ```
>
> br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F6
>
> ```
>      inet addr:169.254.255.1  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
> ```
>
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F6
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
> ```
>      RX packets:610099 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:18 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:931175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>
>      RX bytes:263258272 (251.0 MiB)  TX bytes:833541212 (794.9 MiB)
>      Interrupt:4
> ```
>
> eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B0:C7:45:75:1C:F6
>
> ```
>      inet addr:192.168.2.254  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:5071499 errors:0 dropped:787 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:3681042 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>
>      RX bytes:2519572372 (2.3 GiB)  TX bytes:462892303 (441.4 MiB)
>
>      Interrupt:5
> ```
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>
> ```
>      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>
>      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>
>      RX bytes:37100 (36.2 KiB)  TX bytes:37100 (36.2 KiB)
> ```
>
> mon.ath0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr B0-C7-45-75-1C-F6-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
> ```
>      RX packets:462186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
>
>      RX bytes:105722162 (100.8 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> ```
>
> mon.ath1  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr B0-C7-45-75-1C-F7-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>
> ```
>      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:3114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:32
>
>      RX bytes:377428 (368.5 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> ```
>
> tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>
> ```
>      inet addr:172.16.254.6  P-t-P:172.16.254.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
>
>      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>      RX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>      TX packets:14279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
>
>      RX bytes:22488 (21.9 KiB)  TX bytes:775355 (757.1 KiB)
> ```

**Ping peer IP from server:**

> ping 172.16.254.2
>
> PING 172.16.254.2 (172.16.254.2): 56 data bytes
>
> --- 172.16.254.2 ping statistics ---
>
> 4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

**Ping tun0's client IP address from the server:**

> ping 172.16.254.6
>
> PING 172.16.254.6 (172.16.254.6): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=0 ttl=64 time=30.222 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=1 ttl=64 time=29.536 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=2 ttl=64 time=30.918 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=3 ttl=64 time=30.386 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=4 ttl=64 time=30.788 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.6: seq=5 ttl=64 time=31.271 ms
>
> --- 172.16.254.6 ping statistics ---
>
> 6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
>
> round-trip min/avg/max = 29.536/30.520/31.271 ms

**Ping peer IP from the client:**

> ping 172.16.254.5
>
> PING 172.16.254.5 (172.16.254.5): 56 data bytes
>
> ^C
>   --- 172.16.254.5 ping statistics ---
>
> 7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

**Ping tun21's IP on the server from the client**

> ping 172.16.254.1
>
> PING 172.16.254.1 (172.16.254.1): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=29.253 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=31.730 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 172.16.254.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=30.010 ms
>
> ^C
>
> --- 172.16.254.1 ping statistics ---
>
> 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
>
> round-trip min/avg/max = 29.253/30.331/31.730 ms

I tried adding a route to 10.1.30.0(Client LAN) on the server using the ip 172.16.254.6 but it will only let me map it to 172.16.254.2

> ip route add 10.1.30.0/24 via 172.16.254.6 dev tun21
>
> RTNETLINK answers: No such process
>
> ip route add 10.1.30.0/24 via 172.16.254.2 dev tun21

**Pinging a host on client LAN from the server -- no dice**

> PING 10.1.30.100 (10.1.30.100): 56 data bytes
>
> --- 10.1.30.100 ping statistics ---
>
> 3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

**Ping a host on Server LAN from the client -- no dice**

> ping 10.1.10.100
>
> PING 10.1.10.100 (10.1.10.100): 56 data bytes
>
> ^C
>
> --- 10.1.10.100 ping statistics ---
>
> 2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Logs from the server side:

> LOG:1432700723,D,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 UDPv4 READ [81] from [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:44820: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80
>
> LOG:1432700723,,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 MULTI: bad source address from client [10.1.30.100], packet dropped
>
> LOG:1432700723,D,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 UDPv4 READ [81] from [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:44820: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80
>
> LOG:1432700723,,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 MULTI: bad source address from client [10.1.30.106], packet dropped
>
> LOG:1432700724,D,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 UDPv4 READ [81] from [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:44820: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80
>
> LOG:1432700724,,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 MULTI: bad source address from client [10.1.30.110], packet dropped
>
> 2700729,,Client/x.x.x.x:44820 MULTI: bad source address from client [10.1.30.100], packet dropped

**Logs from the client side:**

> LOG:1432686050,D,UDPv4 WRITE [81] to x.x.x.x:1198: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80
>
> LOG:1432686050,D,UDPv4 WRITE [81] to x.x.x.x:1198: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80
>
> LOG:1432686051,D,UDPv4 WRITE [81] to x.x.x.x:1198: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=80

I even ran a tcpdump on both routers and turns out the packets from LAN on server side aren't even getting to the client router.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the following lines in my config

> route 10.1.30.0 255.255.255.0
>
> push "route 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0"
>
> push "route 10.1.30.0 255.255.255.0"

and added the following lines for my client in the CCD folder

> less /tmp/etc/openvpn/server1/ccd/CALPHA
>
> iroute 10.1.30.0 255.255.255.0